# Code coverage for the two apex classes

Tags: apex, deployment, code-coverage

I have two apex classes with two test classes

First Apex class has code coverage 93%
Second Apex class has code coverage 65%

I want to deploy the above two apex classes tomorrow but i have one class with below 75% of code coverage.

Can you please confirm whether i can validate the change set successfully ?

Comment: [Code coverage steps and considerations prior to deployments](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Code-coverage-steps-and-considerations-prior-to-deployments&type=1)

Answer (score 1):

Before deploying into production, you should validate the changeset in the sandbox where you have exact production replica.

Secondly, it is recommended to have code coverages more than 75% for apex classes and triggers.

If you have a class with 10 lines to code with 93% coverage and second class having 1000 lines of code with 67% coverage then total code coverage will be lesser than 75%.

Refer [Testing Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_best_practices.htm)

Comment: First Apex Class Code Coverage 94% (675/715)
Second Apex Class Code Coverage 65% (1633/2501)

How to calcuate the above Apex classes (What is the formula ) ?

May i know what is the total code coverage of the above two apex classes ?

Comment: whats the harm to increase your coverage from 65% to >75%?

Comment: I don't have enough time ,in case if i dont reach 75% of code coverage of that particular apex class by time it will be a problem. 
I just want to make sure will it this work or what is the formula for the code coverage if i want to calculate for the two apex classes (using lines)

Comment: @SuneelChandrasekhar Its the sum of the covered lines divided by the sum of the total lines. I make that 71% for your two classes.

Comment: (2308/3216)  = 71% . Thanks Keith C ,So it should be 75% of code coverage for succesful validation before deployment .
I am new to salesforce , let say if i have 75% average of code coverage of the above two classes and validate is succesful .When I click quick deploy does it validate the apex class and test class again ?

Comment: Your classes would be easier to test if they weren't enormous monoliths. You should look at design patterns to improve your separation of concerns.